# External Json with autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i try to use an external Json as source for the autocomplete Jquery UI plugin : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I don't understrand the good way, and the good format of the json. In my example, il have in my json : 
["tag1","tag2","tag3"]

The autocomplete seems to work, but if a start to type "a", the autocomplete propose all the tags inside the json. It seems that autocomplete doesn't filter the content of the json, and always shows the whole tag inside the json. 
So, i don't understand how to have the normal behaviour : The autocomplete only propose me "tag1" when i type a "t", for example.

My page is here : 
http://tcdemo.fr/temp/test.html

The Json is here : 
http://tcdemo.fr/temp/search.json

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code there are three things you can do to for a solution:

1. Handle the filtering on the server side and call the ajax function on an endpoint which gives the filtered result
2. If it's a static set of objects, load the json outside the `.tagit()` bind and pass the json result to `availableTags` property. The filtering is handled by default.

   ```
   $("#mytags").tagit({
       availableTags: jsonResult, // search.json is loaded into jsonResult
       show_tag_url: "/tags/",
       singleField: true,
       singleFieldNode: $('#submit_tag_names')
   });
   ```
3. Otherwise if, for some reason prefer your method - filter the success result on the javascript end. Change your success function in your script to:

   ```
   success: function(choices) {
           var filter = search.term.toLowerCase();
           var filteredChoices = $.grep(choices, function(element) {
               // Only match autocomplete options that begin with the search term.
               return (element.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) === 0);
           });
           showChoices(this._subtractArray(filteredChoices, this.assignedTags()));
       }
   ```

Hope this helps